# Retrieving the textual context of a Sphinx search match

Tags: php, search, sphinx

As Sphinx only returns ID's, it's hard to tell where the actual match occured in a matching piece of text. It ofcourse, also depends on the search mode: maybe there are more matches in a document `SPH_MATCH_ANY` or there's only one `SPH_MATCH_PHRASE`.

When the matching mode is set to `SPH_MATCH_PHRASE`, it is kind of easy to retrieve the textual context of the actual match, by for example finding the `strpos("Exact phrase", $string)`. How is it possible to achieve the same thing with `SPH_MATCH_ANY` or `SPH_MATCH_ALL`? Is there a way that Sphinx can return a `strpos` (pointer) to the most relevant match or just the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [BuildExcerpts](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-buildexcerpts) function that will allow you to check what was matched in a particular piece of text.